# Korea Counter for Pages and Chapters in a book

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, translation, meaning, word-choice

Is there a Number Counter for pages? I don't see it. I see one for Books, but not for Pages in a book. Also, is there a counter for Chapter in a book?

I want to refer to Chapter 5, Page 72 when speaking with someone.

https://www.90daykorean.com/korean-counters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that like the user13229973's answer. But I would suggest the different ways. 챕터[chapter] and 페이지[page] are 외래어(Loanword in Korean) Not the original Korean words. As you can see, that was imported from English languages.

So My answer is

In stead of the 챕터[chapter], You can use the word "단원". Plus, Vice versa for the 페이지[page], You can use the word "쪽".  Therefore your answer would be "5단원 72쪽".

In my personal view, "단원" and "쪽" are widely use as much as " 챕터 & 페이지" in the South Korea.

Remark) There are difference between "장" and "쪽". For example "72 장" is expression focusing there are 72 paper. But "72 쪽" is expression focusing the 72 page for a book.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give my answer because I find some parts inaccurate in the existing answers.

The best way to say "Chapter 5, Page 72" in my opinion is (제)**5장 72페이지** or (제)**5장 72쪽** (pronounced 일 장 칠십이 페이지/쪽, not 한 장 ...). We usually don't put space between the figure and the word, but 72페이지 may be written 72 페이지 too since it's a long loan word.

쪽 is the Korean word for a page in a book but I believe 페이지 is a lot more common these days than 쪽.

For more details, here are other related words.

- 단원 (unit, chapter).  This word is typically used in educational contexts.  It also focuses more on the material as a unit than as a series of topics.  It is also rare to call a chapter of a non-academic book like a novel a 단원.
- 챕터 (chapter).  This is sometimes used, especially when you refer to it not with their ordinal number, as in 이 챕터, 다음 챕터, etc (because 이 장 or 다음 장 can sometimes be confused with the other "장" explained below).
- 장 (sheet).  Confusingly for learners, 장 is also a count word for sheets of paper (as listed in the page you linked). This is just a coincidence and 장 as a chapter and 장 as a sheet have different hanja (Chinese character).
- 면 (page).  This is another word for "page", especially when the number of pages is not so high and the size is big, as in newspapers or magazines.

If you are confused with so many answers, I recommend looking up any online English-Korean dictionary (e.g. https://en.dict.naver.com/#/main).  Most of them list 장 as the first Korean word for "chapter" and the ones I checked don't even mention 단원 anywhere.  For "page", it goes "페이지, 쪽, 면 ...".

Hence **5장 72페이지** or **5장 72쪽**.